# -torque-resolution equivalent for static CartoDB maps

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create a Torque map with tooltips. I couldn't see a way to create tooltips on Torque layers, so as a workaround I've created a separate static layer than can be toggled. Toggling this layer sets the SQL to query the data for a point in time corresponding to the current Torque time. The Torque layer does some clustering/aggregation based on the `-torque-resolution` CartoCSS parameter. The problem I am now encountering is that the layers looks slightly different because the static layer doesn't do this clustering. Is there any way to replicate the behaviour of `-torque-resolution` CartoCSS on the static layer with SQL queries or otherwise? I actually want this clustering, so setting this to `-torque-resolution: 1` won't help me in this case.